# Show fullscreen "Access Request" dialog instead of notification when using getAuthToken(...)

Tags: android

I built an AccountAuthenticator for a webservice that I'd like to use in other applications with different signatures. I'd like to instantly show the fullscreen access request dialog (this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/67OHW.png) instead of a notification so that I'm certain I have access to the account before setting my SyncAdapter to sync automatically.

So far I've tried the getAuthToken, one of which shows a notification:

`manager.getAuthToken(account, "full", null, true, callback, new Handler());`

The other throws an exception:

`manager.getAuthToken(account, "full", null, activity, callback, new Handler());`

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Activity to be started with KEY_INTENT must share Authenticator's signatures
        at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$Session.onResult(AccountManagerService.java:2206)
        at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$6.onResult(AccountManagerService.java:1411)
        at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$6.onResult(AccountManagerService.java:1386)
        at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticatorResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticatorResponse.java:59)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)`
```

Is it possible to show the access request dialog without a notification from an app that was signed with a different key?

Comment: This appears to be a problem with Kitkat (4.4+).  Other Android versions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug (or security feature) in KitKat, preventing cross app token sharing.  I recommend you implement token sharing using your own custom intents and security validation, rather than relying on Android's APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good tutorial for this workflow but I was finally able to get this to work in my app.  I am adding this answer for posterity for anyone else coming across this particular use case.

**Running as a Background Task**

```
manager.getAuthToken(account, "full", null, true, callback, new Handler());
```

The above expects you to be running in some background task where you don't need to display UI right away.  The java doc for this method explains this.  Sadly, if you use a "false" flag you don't get a callback that the SecurityException occurred.

**Running in the Foreground**

```
manager.getAuthToken(account, "full", null, activity, callback, new Handler());
```

This expects the app calling this method to share the same signing certificate of the authenticator.  This is where I and many people are getting hung up.  I tried a few versions of android from 4.0.1 onward to 5.0 and it seems to be intended behavior and not a bug in their code.

**The Solution**

Use a different means of getting the auth token.  specifically confirm credentials of the account you need.

```
mgr.confirmCredentials(account, null, activity, callback, null);
```

By supporting Confirm Credentials you can send an intent to launch an AccountAuthenticatorActivity through the Authenticator and avoid the security exception.  You have full control over the UI here so while normally you could request a new password for the account, you could instead show a page with a button to confirm that the account should be used in the calling application.  Then, all you have to do is send the auth token in the AccountManagerCallback bundle going back to the calling app.

**Example Callback Method**

```
new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> bundle) {
        boolean success = result.getBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT);
        if (success) {
            final String token = result.getString(AuthenticationHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN);
            //cache token somewhere local
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution using confirmCredentials(), but I never receive a AccountManagerCallback. Can you please share more details of the whole setup?

Comment: Can you post full solution? I dont think this works.

Comment: I don't have access to this codebase anymore so the implementation may have changed in a later release.  I do remember that you don't get a callback in the event of a security exception so it's important to check the unfiltered logs as you're debugging.