# Is there a way to show a custom dialog for access request for a custom account

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have created a custom account which needs to be accessed by a few apps with different signatures.When the app performs such an access for the first time,the user is prompted with access request dialog.Is it possible to provide a custom UI for that dialog.I have seen [Show fullscreen "Access Request" dialog instead of notification when using getAuthToken(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527528/show-fullscreen-access-request-dialog-instead-of-notification-when-using-getau)  and was wondering if there was any way to avoid this apart from runnign a custom service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Android AccountManager ,this is not possible.However if it your own custom service,you ca n overlay witha  dialog which can do the needful.